# find and replace the value if exists in array using typescript map not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have an array which have set of values without space so I want find the value and replace it with space
For ex:

dateOfJoining --> Date Of Joining

employmentStatus --> EmploymentStatus

```
let attributes =["dateOfJoining", "employmentStatus"]

let filtered = attributes.filter((item) => {
  if (item === 'dateOfJoining') {
    item = 'Date Of Joining';
  }

  if (item === 'employmentStatus') {
    item = 'Employment Status';
  }

  return item;
});
```

its always returning `filtered =["dateOfJoining", "employmentStatus"]` but its needs to return like `["Date Of Joining", "Employment Status"]`.

I have tried with above approach but its not returning the value as expected.
IS their anyway to solve this?

Comment: Is `.filter` the right tool here? Looks like you are trying to transform you array items for which the `.map` method would be better suited. Try using `.map` instead and I think your code may work as-is.

Comment: Use `Array#map` instead

Comment: Filter just tells whether an item should be kept or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `forEach` approach better for this use case.
See example below:

```
let attributes =["dateOfJoining", "employmentStatus"]

 attributes.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (item === 'dateOfJoining') {
    attributes[index] = 'Date Of Joining';
  }

  if (item === 'employmentStatus') {
    attributes[index] = 'Employment Status';
  }
  console.log('-*-*', item);
});
```

And **even better** without using any if else and unlimited number of sentences:

```
let attributes =["dateOfJoining", "employmentStatus", "someOtherText", "andAnotherText"]

attributes.forEach((item, index) => {
  var result = item.replace( /([A-Z])/g, " $1" );
    attributes[index] = result.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + result.slice(1);
});

console.log(attributes);   
// ["Date Of Joining", "Employment Status", "Some Other Text", "And Another Text"]
```

Comment: @BlockHasher did you try this ?

Comment: hey Nadhir, it worked as expected, thanks a ton!

Comment: @BlockHasher great, can you please mark it as it correct answer